# Applying regexp in a column of excel for validation

Tags: excel, excel-2007

I wan to apply a regexp validation on excel.so that if someone enter the wrong value in the cell
the error message should be shown.
for example if i applied the regexp "(\d{10},)*\d{10}" on a column for the valid entries and if someone enter the value "asdfgh" in a cell of that column an error message should be thrown

How can I do this

Comment: Are you sure you really need a regexp? you could use standard DataValidation or Personalized Data Validation as Alexandre pointed out. If you really need regexp, you will have to build some custom VBA.

Answer (score 1):

In Data > Data validation choose "Personnalized" and you can enter a formula. It works much like the formula for conditional formatting. You can use any Excel functions there.

As for the Regex part, I'm pretty sure there is no Regex integrated in Excel. You may want to look at ad-ins for that.

Edit: It does seem that there is a VBA module available for Regex support:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/818802/en-us

Notice that it took me seconds to find this information. Google is your friend.